# Jconfig - XML and properties file: wrong output

Tags: java, xml

I am using Jconfig for configuration. I am using XML and properties files. I have Jconfig.jar, properties file and xml file in classpath.

Properties file `test.properties`:

```
app.site=xyz.com
```

XML file:

```
<properties>
  <include properties="test.properties" />
  <category name="test">
    <app-site>${app.site}</app-site>
  </category>
</properties>
```

In Java code use:

```
String site = config.getProperty("app-site", "test");
```

I am getting ouput as

```
${app.site}
```

No exception or error on console. What is wrong? Can anyone help please.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<property name="app-site" value="${app.site}">` instead of `<app-site>${app.site}</app-site>`